# Opening a window using windows.open() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(){
window.open("http://example.com", "myWindow", "height=150, 
width=150");
}
```

Do I really need to add `"myWindow"` just to load the new window in a size of 
150X150? Whenever I remove the `"myWindow"` code, the sample site is loaded in full-screen. And yes I've tried adding `""` and it worked. Why is it even necessary? I've also tried the code above but doesn't work as well:

```
function myFunction(){
window.open("http://example.com");
window.resizeTo(150, 150)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing ```"myWindow"``` with ```""```?

Comment: @D.Pardal I've tried and yes it worked. But my question was, why was it necessary to include it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the API specifications of [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), you specify the window features in the 3rd parameter. Therefore, you need to set the 2nd parameter, otherwise whatever you specify in the 2nd parameter will be interpreted as the window name.

Comment: I get it now...so the height and width will be applied to the 2nd parameter...thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `_blank` instead of `myWindow.`

Answer (score 0):

window.open is rather browser specific, you need to test it.
There are ethical problems surrounding its use so some attributes do not operate in newer browsers because of malicious javascript programming.

re: popup blockers (ethics of functioning these attributes) !

(may cause user problems) resizable= , fullscreen= , replace=

```
<!-- no DTD no lang no full script tag declaration -->
 <html>

 <head>
   <title> test </title>
 </head>

  <body>
 <script>
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716443/opening-a-window-using-windows-open-in-javascript", "_new", "height=150, width=800, fullscreen=no, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no");
 </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

"myName" as a parameter value is like an id for the early javascript to have a clear reference to the window for programming.

Here's a good link for modern x-browser.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to set a custom name, according to the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) you can set the name string as "_blank" which is the default. This parameter is necessary because all *window.open* parameters are *positional*, that means that if you want to set *specs* you need to define *URL* and *name*.